# Continuity of Component Function

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $f:Z\times X \to Y$ be given such that $f$ is continuous.

I'm trying to prove that $f(z, -)$ is continuous for a fixed $z\in Z$.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if the proof that follows is correct:

1) Let $z\in Z$ be given. Let $x\in X$ be given. We will show that $f(z,-)$ is continuous at $x$ and thus for all $x\in X$.

2) Let $U\in Open(Y)$ be given such that $f(z,x)\in U$.

3) Because $f$ is continuous at $(z,x)$, there must exist some $V\in Open(Z\times X)$ such that $f(z,x)\in f(V)\subseteq U$.

4) By the definition of the product topology, that means that $V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}V_\alpha \times W_\alpha$ for some $A$, and $\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A} \times \{W_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}\subseteq Open(Z)\times Open(X)$.

5) Because $(z,x)\in V$, there must exist some $\alpha_0 \in A$ such that $(z,x)\in V_{\alpha_0}\times W_{\alpha_0}$.

6) Then $W_{\alpha_0}$ is the sought after neighborhoud of $x$:

6.1) $W_{\alpha_0} \in Open(X)$.

6.2) $x\in W_{\alpha_0}$.

6.3) $f(z,x)\in f(z,W_{\alpha_0})\subseteq f(V)\subseteq U$

$\boxed{\,}$

Comment: It's good. In 3), however, you could add that $(z,x)\in V$, but you you do that in 5), so it's okay. You could also prove your claim by writing the map as a composition of continuous maps $X\to Z\times X\to Y$.